# Is the usage of the participle clause correct, here?

Tags: participle-clauses

I read in Advanced Grammer In Use that sometimes the participle clause has its own subject, like:

> The collection of vases is priceless, **some** **being** over two thousand years old.

According to the above rule, I want to write the same sentence for this snapshot, https://ieltsmaterial.com/ielts-academic-writing-task-1-map-band-9-model-sample/, like below. Is the below sentence correct?

> The evergreen trees on the west of the district do not undergo a change in their numbers, **some** grown on the east of the island **demolishing**,

Comment: No, your second version isn't syntactically valid. Note that although it's "valid" to "front" the participial clause in the first *(Some being over two thousand years old, the collection of vases is priceless)*, this would be extremely unnatural for that *specific* example. But *your* example starts with the word ***while***, which unlike ***some***, is NOT a "subject" for the participial clause*. I'm not sure exactly what your example is trying to say, so I can't easily come up with a "valid" version that *does* include its own subject within a participial clause.

Comment: ...also note that whole purpose of the first example is to showcase the use of ***some*** as an "embedded subject" in the participial clause. Overriding the normal default, whereby the subject would be assumed to be preceding ***collection***, rather than ***some** [vases]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I slightly changed the sentence and added some information about what I want to do.

Comment: oic. Now your text is (almost) syntactically valid. But it doesn't work because ***demolishing*** (tearing down, destroying) is the wrong participle. The word you probably want there is ***diminishing*** (getting less, shrinking).

Comment: ...BUT semantically it still doesn't really make sense, because you're saying the population [as a whole?] remains constant, AT THE SAME TIME AS (the "purpose" of including a participial phrase) you're saying that in ***some*** areas, it's going down.

Comment: ...that's like saying *The people in Britain are remarkably peaceful, **some being psychotic madmen**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Would I ask you to re-write my sentence in the correct form? Thank you in advance

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Is "oic" an abbreviation? Or is it equal to "oik"?

Comment: "Eye dialect" - *Oh, I see [what you mean]*. We're well into Off Topic "proofreading" territory here, but for a syntactically / semantically valid version of something *similar* to your example: *The evergreen trees on the west of the district are not undergoing a significant change in their numbers, some on the east of the island **even diminishing***. But to be honest even though that's "valid", it's nowhere near "idiomatic". We really should have started with a different example, if you want to understand how an ***explicit subject in a participial clause*** might work.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica please put your last comment as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry - no can do. I'm glad if my comment has helped you, but as things stand the question is still OffTopic *proofreading*, for which I see no reason to retract my closevote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I fully agree with FumbleFingers' assertion that

> The collection of vases is priceless, some being over 2000 years old

is **extremely unnatural.** I agree I'd prefer as a matter of style

> The collection of vases, some [being] over 2000 years old, is priceless.

But the key point is that "some being over 2000 years old" is a modifier of "vases" that explains "priceless. I am not sure that it is helpful to think of "some" as an independent subject in this case, but I will not argue about what people call things.

Leaving aside the fact that "demolishing" makes no sense in this context, your variant does not work because you are not modifying "trees on the west" with "grown," but introducing a whole new, contrasting subject. Moreover, if you meant "decreasing," "some" does not make sense if you are talking about the entire population.

> The population of evergreens growing in the west of the district is stable, but that growing in the east is declining

is grammatical. And I'd prefer to say that "that" is the subject of "is" and "growing" modifies that subject. But let's not argue about names.